# Android App Intune Configuration Designer Not Showing

Tags: android, mdm, intune, android-work-profile

I have a workforce app that can be installed from the Play Store and Intune.

When the app is installed and used from Intune Managed Device, I need to report `Intune Device ID` back to my backend so that we can cross-reference some data with MS Graph API.

The docs say IF your app is configured, you can access the Configuration Designer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/app-configuration-policies-use-android#use-the-configuration-designer and send values, like `Intune Device ID` through a configuration policy.

I added the Intune Android SDK to my Android app, however, the Configuration designer doesn't show at all, as it does for MS Authenticator App for example.

My App[image: no config]

MS Authenticator[image]

How do I get the configuration to show for my app?

How Do I configure the app policy to set `Intune Device ID` so that I can read my app?

I would be happy with other identifiable device information.